# How can you automatically change the display of an object? [Python]

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose you have an `object called e_book that` simulate an electronic book. Functionality to be achieved is that every time you execute `"print(e_book)"`, **the printed display will behave like flipping through the pages.**

For example, execute "print(e_book)" the `first time`:

```
"All happy families are alike."
```

execute "print(e_book)" the `second time` displayed content will change:

```
"Each unhappy family is unhappy in its own way."
```

and the `third time` it will change again, and so on.

To sum up, **I want to control the string display of an object by simply calling "print(object_name)"**. Is this achievable?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have no idea how to achieve this so I posted this question.

Comment: We are not going to write all the code for you. Show us some effort (and code)!

Comment: I think what the OP wants to know, is, whether this is achievable. The answer would be yes.

Answer (score 1):

To control the display of an objet, override the **repr** method in your class

```
def __repr__(self):
   return 'whatever'
```

You can also redefine the **str** method.

Answer (score 1):

```py
class EBOOK():
    def __init__(self):
        self.pages = list()
        self.seenPages = -1

    def addPage(self, data):
        self.pages.append(data)

    def __repr__(self):
        self.seenPages += 1
        return str(self.pages[self.seenPages])
        

e_book = EBOOK()

e_book.addPage("All happy families are alike.")
e_book.addPage("Each unhappy family is unhappy in its own way.")

print(e_book)
print(e_book)
```

should produce:

```
All happy families are alike.
Each unhappy family is unhappy in its own way.
```

Comment: I am really curious if this can be done via generator functions.

Comment: Thank you so much for this ingenious solution!

Comment: If this answers your question, you might want to accept it!